# Calculate other angles based on known rotation angle

Tags: math, trigonometry

I am making a mechanical system animation on OpenGL and having a little trouble calculating the rotations angle of the connecting rods based on a known rotation angle A and the position of the point D.

[image]

I need to calculate the angle CDE and CBG as well as the position of point E based on angle A and the position of D. But my high school is failing me right now. I have tried several ways but they all lead to nothing.

The length of segment DA is also known.

Do you have any ideas on how to do that? What should I do?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question... it's a math question, and you'd likely get better results asking on http://math.stackexchange.com,  That said, you should look at the Wikipedia entry on inner product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) particularly the section on orthogonality, which shows how to calculate the angle between two vectors.  You may be able to simplify things if D and E both have the same y value, and B and G likewise have the same y value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to make a few assumptions, and while I was finding a solution I forgot to check the labels so below is an image to clarify point and line name, including in red the  geometry used to solve.

[image: geometry and labels]

Assumptions.

- Points **A** and **B** are fixed.
- Lines **BC**, **FC**, and **DC** are all the same length **L**
- Point **D** is constrained to the line **EG**
- **Angle** not labeled is the angle you refer to in the question.
- The point **F** is on the circle centered at **A**. I forgot to label the **radius** and **angle**.
- Point **A** is at the origin `{x: 0, y: 0}`

I also assume that you know the basics of vector math and that the problem is not finding the angle between lines or vectors, but rather solving to find the points **C** and **D** that is giving you troubles (hope so as this is going to be a long answer for me).

### Solving

Depending on the value of **L** and the position of the constraining line **EG** there may not be a solution for all positions of **F**. The method below will result in either some values being `NaN` or the position of **D** will be incorrect.

#### Find C

Easy start. As **A** is at the origin then  **F** is at `F.x = cos(angle) * radius`, `F.y = sin(angle) * radius`

Now find the mid **m** point on the line **FB** and the length of the line **Bm** as **b**

This forms the right triangle **mBC** and we know the length of **BC** === **L** and just calculated length of line **Bm** === **b** thus the length of the line **mC** is `(L * L - b * b) ** 0.5`

Create a unit vector (normalized) from **F** to **B**, rotate it clockwise 90 deg and scale it by the calculated length of **mC**. Add that vector to the point **m** and you have **C**

```
 // vector 
 nx = B.x - F.x;
 ny = B.y - F.y;
 
 // Normalize, scale, rotate and add to m to get C. shorthand
 // mC len of line mC
 s = mC  / (nx * nx + ny * ny) ** 0.5;
 C.x = m.x - ny * s;
 C.y = m.y + nx * s;

 // OR in steps

 // normalize
 len = (nx * nx + ny * ny) ** 0.5;
 nx /= len;
 ny /= len;

 // scale to length of mC
 nx *= mC;
 ny *= mC;

 // rotated 90CW and add to m to get C
 C.x = m.x - ny;
 C.y = m.y + nx;
```

#### Find D

Now that we have the point **C** we know that the point **D** is on the constraining line **EG**. Thus we know that the point **D** is at the point where a circle at **C** or radius **L** intercepts the line **EG**

However there are two solutions to the intercept of circle and line, the point **B** is at one of these points if **B** is on the line **EG**. If **B** is not on the line **EG** then you will have to pick which of the two solutions you want. Likely the point **D** is the furthest from **B**

There are several methods to find the intercepts of a line and a circle. The following is a little more complex but will help when picking which point to use

```
    // line EG as vec
    vxA = G.x - E.x;
    vyA = G.y - E.y;

    // square of length line EG
    lenA = vxA * vxA + vyA * vyA;

    // vector from E to C
    vxB = C.x - E.x;
    vyB = C.y - E.y;

    // square of length line EC
    lenB = vxB * vxB + vyB * vyB;

    // dot product A.B * - 2
    b = -2 * (vxB * vxA + vyB * vyA);

    // Stuff I forget what its called
    d = (b * b - 4 * lenA * (lenB - L * L)) ** 0.5; // L is length of CD

    // is there a solution if not we are done
    if (isNaN(d)) { return }

    // there are two solution (even if the same point)
    // Solutions as unit distances along line EG 
    u1 = (b - d) / (2 * lenA);
    u2 = (b + d) / (2 * lenA);  // this is the one we want
```

The second unit distance is the one that will fit your layout example. So now we just find the point at `u2` on the line **EG** and we have the final point **D**

```
    D.x = E.x + u2 * (G.x - E.x);
    D.y = E.y + u2 * (G.y - E.y);
```

#### The angles

In your question it is a little ambiguous to me which angles you want. So I will just give you a method to find the angle between to lines. Eg `CB` and `CD`

Convert both lines to vectors. The cross product of these vectors divided by the square root of the product of the squared lengths gives us the sin of the angle. However we still need the quadrant. We workout which quadrant by checking the sign of the dot product of the two vectors.

**Note** this method will find the the smallest angle between the two lines and is invariant to the order of the lines

**Note** the angle is in radians

```
    // vector CB
    xA = B.x - C.x;
    yA = B.y - C.y;

    // vector CD
    xB = D.x - C.x;
    yB = D.y - C.y;

    // square root of the product of the squared lengths
    l = ((xa * xa + ya * ya) * (xb * xb + yb * yb)) ** 0.5;

    // if this is 0 then angle between lines is 0
    if (l === 0) { return 0 } // return angle

    angle = Math.asin((xa  * yb  - ya * xb) / l);  // get angle quadrant undefined

    // if dot of the vectors is < 0 then angle is in quadrants 2 or 3. get angle and return
    if (xa  * xb  + ya * yb < 0) { 
        return (angle< 0 ? -Math.PI: Math.PI) - angle;
    }
    
    // else the angle is in quads 1 or 4 so just return the angle
    return angle;
```

### DONE

To make sure it all worked I have created an interactive diagram. The code of interest is at the top. Variables names are as in my diagram at top of answer. Most of the code is just cut and paste vector libs and UI stuff unrelated to the answer.

#### To use

The diagram will scale to fit the page so click full page if needed.

Use the mouse to drag points with white circles around. For example to rotate **F** around **A** click and drag it.

The white line segment **El** sets the length of the lines **CF**, **CB**, **CD**. The radius of circle at A is set by moving the white circle point to the right of it.

Move mouse out of form to animate.

Mouse only interface.

Overkill but its done.

```js
setTimeout(() => {

    // points and lines as in diagram of answer
    const A = new Vec2(-100,100);
    const B = new Vec2(-240, - 100);
    const C = new Vec2();
    const D = new Vec2();
    const E = new Vec2(-300, -100);
    const F = new Vec2();
    const G = new Vec2(200, -100);
    const AF = new Line2(A, F), FA = new Line2(F, A);
    const BC = new Line2(B, C), CB = new Line2(C, B);
    const CD = new Line2(C, D), DC = new Line2(D, C);
    const EG = new Line2(E, G), GE = new Line2(G, E);
    const FB = new Line2(F, B), BF = new Line2(B, F);
    const FC = new Line2(F, C), CF = new Line2(C, F);
    
    // Math to find points C and D
    function findCandD() {
        F.initPolar(angle, radius).add(A)            // Get position of F
        FB.unitDistOn(0.5, m);                       // Find point midway between F, B, store as m
        // Using right triangle m, B, C the hypot BC length is L
        var c = (FB.length * 0.5) ** 2;              // Half the length of FB squared
        const clLen = (L * L - c) ** 0.5             // Length of line mC
        FB.asVec(v1).rotate90CW().length = clLen;    // Create vector v1 at 90 from FB and length clLen
        C.init(m).add(v1);                           // Add v1 to m to get point C
        const I = EG.unitInterceptsCircle(C, L, cI); // Point D is L dist from 
        if (EG.unitInterceptsCircle(C, L, cI)) {     // Point D is L dist from C. thus us the intercept of corcle radius L and constraining line EG
            EG.unitDistanceOn(cI.y, D)               // Use second intercept as first could be at point B
        } else { C.x = NaN }                         // C is too far from constraining line EG for a solution
         // At this point, the line CD may be the wrong length. Check the length CD is correct
        blk = Math.isSmall(CD.length - L) ? black : red;  // Mark all in red if no solution
    }    
    
    
    
    // Here on down UI, and all the support code
    requestAnimationFrame(update);    
    
    const refRes = 512;
    var scale = 1;
    const mousePos = new Vec2();
    var w = 0, h = 0, cw = 0, ch = 0;
    var frame = 0;
    const m  = new Vec2();  // holds mid point on line BF
    const m1 = new Vec2();
    const v1 = new Vec2();  // temp vector
    const v2 = new Vec2();  // temp vector
    const cI = new Vec2();  // circle intercepts
    var radius = 100;
    var L = 200
    var angle = 1;
    const aa = new Vec2(A.x + radius, A.y);
    const al = new Vec2(E.x + L, E.y);
    const rad = new Line2(A, aa);
    const cl = new Line2(m, C)
    const armLen = new Line2(E, al);
    var blk = "#000"
    const wht = "#FFF"
    const red = "#F00"
    const black = "#000"
    const ui = Vecs2([A, B, aa, E, G, al, F])
    function update(timer){
        frame ++;
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
        if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
            cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
            ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
            scale = Math.min(w / refRes, h / refRes);
        } else {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
        mousePos.init(mouse);
        mousePos.x = (mousePos.x - canvas.width / 2) / scale;
        mousePos.y = (mousePos.y -canvas.height / 2) / scale;
        mousePos.button = mouse.button;
        ctx.font = "24px Arial black"
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        const nearest = ui.dragable(mousePos, 20);
        if (nearest === A) {
            aa.y = A.y
            aa.x = A.x + radius;
        } else if(nearest === F){
            angle = A.directionTo(F);
        } else if(nearest === aa){
            aa.y = A.y
            radius = rad.length;
        } else if (nearest === E) {
            EG.distanceAlong(L, al)
        } else if (nearest === G || nearest === al) {
            EG.nearestOnLine(al, al)
            L = armLen.length;
        }
        if (nearest) {
            canvas.style.cursor = ui.dragging ? "none" : "move";
            nearest.draw(ctx, "#F00", 2, 4);
            if (nearest.isLine2) {
                nearest.nearestOnLine(mousePos, onLine).draw(ctx, "#FFF", 2, 2)
            }
        } else {
            canvas.style.cursor = "default";
        }
        angle += SPEED;
        findCandD();
        ui.mark(ctx, wht, 1, 4);
        ui.mark(ctx, wht, 1, 14);
        armLen.draw(ctx,wht,2)
        EG.draw(ctx, wht, 1)
        ctx.fillStyle = wht;
        ctx.fillText("E", E.x, E.y - 16)
        ctx.fillText("G", G.x, G.y - 16)
        ctx.fillText("l", armLen.p2.x, armLen.p2.y - 16)
        FC.draw(ctx, blk, 4)
        BC.draw(ctx, blk, 4)
        CD.draw(ctx, blk, 4)  
        A.draw(ctx, blk, 2, radius);
        C.draw(ctx, blk, 4, 4)
        F.draw(ctx, blk, 4, 4)
        B.draw(ctx, blk, 4, 4);
        D.draw(ctx, blk, 4, 4)
        ctx.fillStyle = blk;
        ctx.fillText("B", B.x, B.y - 16)
        ctx.fillText("A", A.x, A.y - 16)
        ctx.fillText("F", F.x, F.y + 26)
        ctx.fillText("D", D.x, D.y - 16)
        ctx.fillText("C", C.x, C.y - 16)
        ctx.font = "16px Arial";
        drawAngle(C, CD, CB, 40, B.add(Vec2.Vec(60, -50), Vec2.Vec()), ctx, blk, 2);
        drawAngle(C, CF, CB, 50, A.add(Vec2.Vec(-160, 0), Vec2.Vec()), ctx, blk, 2);
        drawAngle(C, CD, CF, 60, A.add(Vec2.Vec(300, 20), Vec2.Vec()), ctx, blk, 2);
        blk = Math.isSmall(CD.length - L) ? black : red;
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
}, 0);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse  = {x: 0, y: 0, ox: 0, oy: 0, button: false, callback: undefined}
function mouseEvents(e) {
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down", "up", "move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
var SPEED = 0.05;
canvas.addEventListener("mouseover",() => SPEED = 0);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",() => SPEED = 0.05);
Math.EPSILON = 1e-6;
Math.isSmall = val => Math.abs(val) < Math.EPSILON;
Math.isUnit = u => !(u < 0 || u > 1);
Math.uClamp = u => u <= 0 ? 0 : u >= 1 ? 1 : u; // almost 2* faster than Math.min, Math.Max method
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
Math.randI = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m | 0;
Math.rad2Deg = r => r * 180 / Math.PI;
Math.symbols = {};
Math.symbols.degrees = "°";
/* export {Vec2, Line2} */ // this should be a module
var temp;
function Vec2(x = 0, y = (temp = x, x === 0 ? (x = 0 , 0) : (x = x.x, temp.y))) { this.x = x; this.y = y }
Vec2.Vec = (x, y) => ({x, y}); // Vec2 like
Vec2.prototype = {
    isVec2: true,
    init(x, y = (temp = x, x = x.x, temp.y)) { this.x = x; this.y = y; return this }, // assumes x is a Vec2 if y is undefined
    initPolar(dir, length = (temp = dir, dir = dir.x, temp.y)) { this.x = Math.cos(dir) * length; this.y = Math.sin(dir) * length; return this },
    toPolar(res = this) {
        const dir = this.direction, len = this.length;
        res.x = dir;
        res.y = length;
        return res;
    },
    zero() { this.x = this.y = 0; return this },
    initUnit(dir) { this.x = Math.cos(dir); this.y = Math.sin(dir); return this },
    copy() { return new Vec2(this) },
    equal(v) { return (this.x - v.x) === 0 && (this.y - v.y) === 0 },
    isUnits() { return Math.isUnit(this.x) && Math.isUnit(this.y) },
    add(v, res = this) { res.x = this.x + v.x; res.y = this.y + v.y; return res },
    addScaled(v, scale, res = this) { res.x = this.x + v.x * scale; res.y = this.y + v.y * scale; return res },
    sub(v, res = this) { res.x = this.x - v.x; res.y = this.y - v.y; return res },
    scale(val, res = this) { res.x = this.x * val; res.y = this.y * val; return res },
    invScale(val, res = this) { res.x = this.x / val; res.y = this.y / val; return res },
    dot(v) { return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y },
    uDot(v, div) { return (this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y) / div },
    cross(v) { return this.x * v.y - this.y * v.x },
    uCross(v, div) { return (this.x * v.y - this.y * v.x) / div },
    get direction() { return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x) },
    set direction(dir) { this.initPolar(dir, this.length) },
    get length() { return this.lengthSqr ** 0.5 },
    set length(l) { this.scale(l / this.length) },
    get lengthSqr() { return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y },
    set lengthSqr(lSqr) { this.scale(lSqr ** 0.5 / this.length) },
    distanceFrom(vec) { return ((this.x - vec.x) ** 2 + (this.y - vec.y) ** 2) ** 0.5 },
    distanceSqrFrom(vec) { return ((this.x - vec.x) ** 2 + (this.y - vec.y) ** 2) },
    directionTo(vec) { return Math.atan2(vec.y - this.y, vec.x - this.x) },
    normalize(res = this) { return this.invScale(this.length, res) },
    rotate90CW(res = this) {
        const y = this.x;
        res.x = -this.y;
        res.y = y;
        return res;
    },
    angleTo(vec) {
        const xa = this.x, ya = this.y;
        const xb = vec.x, yb = vec.y;
        const l = ((xa * xa + ya * ya) * (xb * xb + yb * yb)) ** 0.5;
        var ang = 0;
        if (l !== 0) {
            ang = Math.asin((xa  * yb  - ya * xb) / l);
            if (xa  * xb  + ya * yb < 0) { return (ang < 0 ? -Math.PI: Math.PI) - ang }
        }
        return ang;
    },
    drawFrom(v, ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth, scale = 1) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(v.x, v.y);
        ctx.lineTo(v.x + this.x * scale, v.y + this.y * scale);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    draw(ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth, size = 4) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, size, 0, Math.TAU);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    path(ctx, size) {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x + size, this.y);
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, size, 0, Math.TAU);
    },
    toString(digits = 3) { return "{x: " + this.x.toFixed(digits) + ", y: " + this.y.toFixed(digits) + "}" },
};
function Vecs2(vecsOrLength) {
    const vecs2 = Object.assign([], Vecs2.prototype);
    if (Array.isArray(vecsOrLength)) { vecs2.push(...vecsOrLength) }
    else if (vecsOrLength && vecsOrLength >= 1) {
        while (vecsOrLength-- > 0) { vecs2.push(new Vec2()) }
    }
    return vecs2;
}
Vecs2.prototype = {
    isVecs2: true,
    nearest(vec, maxDist = Infinity, tolerance = 1) { // max for argument semantic, used as semantic min in function
        var found;
        for (const v of this) {
            const dist = v.distanceFrom(vec);
            if (dist < maxDist) {
                if (dist <= tolerance) { return v }
                maxDist = dist;
                found = v;
            }
        }
        return found;
    },
    copy() {
        var idx = 0;
        const copy = Vecs2(this.length);
        for(const p of this) { copy[idx++].init(p) }
        return copy;
    },
    uniformTransform(rMat, pMat, res = this) {
        var idx = 0;
        for(const p of this) {  p.uniformTransform(rMat, pMat, res[idx++]) }
    },
    mark(ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth, size = 4) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const p of this) { p.path(ctx, size) }
        ctx.stroke();
    },    
    draw(ctx, close = false, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const p of this) { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y) }
        close && ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    path(ctx, first = true) {
        for (const p of this) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            } else { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y) }
        }
    },
    dragable(mouse, maxDist = Infinity, tolerance = 1) {
        var near;
        if (this.length) {
            if (!this.dragging) {
                if (!this.offset) { this.offset = new Vec2() }
                near = this.nearest(this.offset.init(mouse), maxDist, tolerance); // mouse may not be a Vec2
                if (near && mouse.button) {
                    this.dragging = near;
                    this.offset.init(near).sub(mouse);
                }
            }
            if (this.dragging) {
                near = this.dragging;
                if (mouse.button) { this.dragging.init(mouse).add(this.offset) }
                else { this.dragging = undefined }
            }
        }
        return near;
    }
}
function Line2(p1 = new Vec2(), p2 = (temp = p1, p1 = p1.p1 ? p1.p1 : p1, temp.p2 ? temp.p2 : new Vec2())) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
}
Line2.prototype = {
    isLine2: true,
    init(p1, p2 = (temp = p1, p1 = p1.p1, temp.p2)) { this.p1.init(p1); this.p2.init(p2) },
    copy() { return new Line2(this) },
    asVec(res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res) },
    unitDistOn(u, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res).scale(u).add(this.p1) },
    unitDistanceOn(u, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res).scale(u).add(this.p1) },
    distAlong(dist, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res).uDot(res, res.length).add(this.p1) },
    distanceAlong(dist, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res).scale(dist / res.length).add(this.p1) },
    get length() { return this.lengthSqr ** 0.5 },
    get lengthSqr() { return (this.p1.x - this.p2.x) ** 2 + (this.p1.y - this.p2.y) ** 2 },
    get direction() { return this.asVec(wV2).direction },
    translate(vec, res = this) {
        this.p1.add(vec, res.p1);
        this.p2.add(vec, res.p2);
        return res;
    },
    reflect(line, u, res = line) {
        this.asVec(wV2).normalize();
        line.asVec(wV1);
        line.unitDistOn(u, res.p1);
        const d = wV1.uDot(wV2, 0.5);
        wV3.init(wV2.x * d - wV1.x, wV2.y * d - wV1.y);
        res.p1.add(wV3.scale(1 - u), res.p2);
        return res;
    },
    reflectAsUnitVec(line, u, res = new Vec2()) {
        this.asVec(res).normalize();
        line.asVec(wV1);
        return res.scale(wV1.uDot(res, 0.5)).sub(wV1).normalize()
    },
    angleTo(line) { return this.asVec(wV1).angleTo(line.asVec(wV2)) },
    translateNormal(amount, res = this) {
        this.asVec(wV1).rot90CW().length = -amount;
        this.translate(wV1, res);
        return res;
    },
    distanceNearestVec(vec) { // WARNING!! distanceLineFromVec is (and others are) dependent on vars used in this function
        return this.asVec(wV1).uDot(vec.sub(this.p1, wV2), wV1.length);
    },
    unitNearestVec(vec) { // WARNING!! distanceLineFromVec is (and others are) dependent on vars used in this function
        return this.asVec(wV1).uDot(vec.sub(this.p1, wV2), wV1.lengthSqr);
    },
    nearestOnLine(vec, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p1.addScaled(wV1, this.unitNearestVec(vec), res) },
    nearestOnSegment(vec, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p1.addScaled(wV1, Math.uClamp(this.unitNearestVec(vec)), res) },
    distanceLineFromVec(vec) { return this.nearestOnLine(vec, wV1).sub(vec).length },
    distanceSegmentFromVec(vec) { return this.nearestOnSegment(vec, wV1).sub(vec).length },
    unitInterceptsLine(line, res = new Vec2()) {  // segments
        this.asVec(wV1);
        line.asVec(wV2);
        const c = wV1.cross(wV2);
        if (Math.isSmall(c)) { return }
        wV3.init(this.p1).sub(line.p1);
        res.init(wV1.uCross(wV3, c), wV2.uCross(wV3, c));
        return res;
    },
    unitInterceptsCircle(point, radius, res = new Vec2()) {
        this.asVec(wV1);
        var b = -2 * this.p1.sub(point, wV2).dot(wV1);
        const c = 2 * wV1.lengthSqr;
        const d = (b * b - 2 * c * (wV2.lengthSqr - radius * radius)) ** 0.5
        if (isNaN(d)) { return }
        return res.init((b - d) / c, (b + d) / c);
    },
    draw(ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(this.p1.x, this.p1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.p2.x, this.p2.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    path(ctx) {
        ctx.moveTo(this.p1.x, this.p1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.p2.x, this.p2.y);
    },
    toString(digits = 3) { return "{ p1: " + this.p1.toString(digits) + ", p2: "  + this.p2.toString(digits) + "}" },
};

const wV1 = new Vec2(), wV2 = new Vec2(), wV3 = new Vec2(); // pre allocated work vectors used by Line2 functions
const wVA1 = new Vec2(), wVA2 = new Vec2(), wVA3 = new Vec2(); // pre allocated work vectors 
const wVL1 = new Vec2(), wVL2 = new Vec2(), wVL3 = new Vec2(); // pre allocated work vectors used by Line2Array functions
const wL1 = new Line2(), wL2 = new Line2(), wL3 = new Line2(); // pre allocated work lines
function drawLable(text, from, to, ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth) {
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.lineWidth = lw;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(from.x, from.y);
    ctx.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
    ctx.stroke();   
    const w = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    var offset = 8;
    if (from.x < to.x) { ctx.fillText(text, to.x + offset + w / 2, to.y) }
    else { ctx.fillText(text, to.x - offset - w / 2, to.y) }
}
function drawAngle(pos, lineA, lineB, radius, lablePos, ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.lineWidth = lw;
    const from = lineA.direction;
    const angle = lineA.angleTo(lineB);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, from, from + angle, angle < 0);
    ctx.stroke();   
    drawLable(
        Math.rad2Deg(angle).toFixed(2) + Math.symbols.degrees,
        Vec2.Vec(
            pos.x + Math.cos(from + angle / 2) * radius, 
            pos.y + Math.sin(from + angle / 2) * radius
        ),
        lablePos,
        ctx,
        col,
        lw / 2,
    );
}
```

```css
canvas { 
    position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; 
    background: #4D8;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your time writing such a thorough answer with some nice sample code! As you said, I've too focused on finding the angles so that I can't see the problem here is finding the position of point C. Thank you once again!